# Windows and Ubuntu dual boot: Windows is fixing itself and it can't

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi

how are you?

TL;DR: After installing Ubuntu 18.4 LTS, Windows 10 won't start. Windows tries to fix itself and it doesn't work, I had recovery screen. I know it's duplicate, but I swear I did every thing recommended in other questions. And it may be part of problem.

Sorry for wrong naming, I translated options from another language.

For many years I had Windows 7 (gaming) and Ubuntu (work) on dual boot and loved it. 3 days ago I bought Windows 10 and I simply can't make it work. I read so many post and typed so many commands, that it can be something I did previously. I hope I'm not wasting your time.

- What I did:

  - I installed Windows 10, I was working
  - I installed Ubuntu 18.04 LTS with option "Install next to Windows"
  - After that windows booted, I checked Windows mode and it's UEFI
  - I changed loader to GRUB in BIOS and choose boot mode to UEFI (instead of UEFI and Legacy)
  - I saw GRUB menu and choose Ubuntu. It's working :)
  - I restarted computer and choose Windows in GRUB menu
  - Windows started loading, but it tried to fix itself. It didn't work and showed me "Close system" or "Advanced Options". I looked at Advanced Options and didn't know what to do, so I googled the problem.
  - I downloaded boot-repair, choose Standard fix, it added many options to GRUB menu, but none of them is working
  - I choose advanced options in boot-repair and checked if GRUB localization has boot/efi partition checked. Yes, It's checked.
  - MBR Options are greyed out
  - Repair Windows boot files is greyed out, I read something about it, but I still don't know why.
  - In BIOS I have disabled secure boot. Windows still doesn't load.
  - I disabled Windows fast boot via command (HiberbootEnabled). Windows still doesn't load correctly.
  - I tried first answer from 217904 question and problem is still the same.

**But now I have some report: http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/2sfszV23XB/** I read it and there are some
   issues, but I don't have knowledge to understand it.

My Grub config:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

UEFI test:

```
kamila@UBUNTU-STACJONARnY:~$ [ -d /sys/firmware/efi ] && echo "EFI boot on HDD" || echo "Legacy boot on HDD" 
EFI boot on HDD
```

Please, can someone help me? I tried to fix it for 3 days.

EDIT: It's same as [Windows 10 (dual boot) doesn't start anymore!](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1077332/windows-10-dual-boot-doesnt-start-anymore), but only answer is reinstall Windows, because you installed Windows on wrong partition. I had one partition with Windows and it was Ubuntu installed who separated partitions.

EDIT: I changed Windows OS Configuration in BIOS from CSM to UEFI. Windows is still not working.

**RESOLVED:**
I tried to fix Windows installation for many hours, but only reinstalling Windows helped.

- be sure to set BIOS options before installation. I changed all options to UEFI (Windows OS Configuration && Boot mode)
- I deleted all partitions,
- be sure you have only one hard drive installed (I had second drive with backup files while windows installation, maybe it was that? But Windows worked without it and I plug it out after Windows installation)
- be sure you have hibernation off
- Now you can install Windows and Ubuntu

Sorry for taking you time and I hope this post will help someone :)

Comment: Before you go any further please make a backup of your important data and verify it matches the source files (checksumming is OK). Then, make another backup to a different destination (whether cloud or a different drive) and verify that.

Comment: Windows is gaming PC and all saves are in the cloud, On Ubuntu I didn't have anything so we are save to go!
I also have old thinkpad, so if something goes wrong, I will be able to comment

Comment: In Ubuntu run `grep -i -A10 'windows boot manager' /boot/grub/grub.cfg` and post result.

Comment: I sorry I bothered you, but I managed to solve problem 1 minute ago. For future problems:

- be sure to set BIOS options before installation. I changed all options to UEFI (Windows OS Configuration && Boot mode), I deleted all partitions, I installed Windows again and Ubuntu. It works!
- be sure you have only one hard drive installed (I had second drive with backup files while windows installation, maybe it was that? But Windows worked without it)
- be sure you have hibernation off 

Sorry for taking your time and thank you :) Ubuntu is great <3

Comment: Dual boots work fine with 2 disks. I use that arrangement myself.